# Расшифровка задания

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Пытаясь расшифровать домашнее, зашел в тупик(

Вот задание:

> Создать базовый класс – автомобиль, который должен содержать элементы-данные: число колёс и мощность двигателя, а также виртуальную функцию, выдающую эти данные на консоль.
>
> Создать производные классы – автобус и грузовик, содержащие данные: число пассажиров для автобуса, грузоподъёмность для грузовика. **Переопределить унаследованную функцию так, чтобы в производных классах она выводила все данные об объектах.
> Все классы должны быть в ортодоксальной канонической форме.**
>
> **Создать функцию, выдающую на консоль данные об объекте, не имея сведений о том, объектом какого класса является входной параметр.**

Расшифруйте, что должна делать эта унаследованная функция? Это виртуальная функция? Каким образом выводила... Я торможу... (
Что за каноническая ортодок... что это!? И как можно создать последнее?? Введу я 180, а у класса приватное значение =180... его вывожу, так?? Вообще запутался...

Вроде написал основные наследования - не сложно, с этими делами я знаком...

Answer (score 4):

Погуглил на словосочетание «ортодоксальная каноническая форма».

Вылезло вот это: http://opensource.com.ua/contents/978546900189p.html.

> Конкретные типы данных следует отличать от реализаций классов, о которых рассказывалось в предыдущей главе. Конкретные типы работают по таким же предсказуемым правилам, что и встроенные типы C (скажем, int). Они создаются по специальному образцу, в котором члены классов конкретных типов данных передают информацию системе поддержки типов компилятора C++. Это позволяет компилятору генерировать эффективный и надежный код для абстракций произвольной сложности. Мы будем называть эту форму ортодоксальной канонической формой класса. Термин "каноническая” означает, что форма определяет систему правил, которые должны соблюдаться компилятором при генерировании кода, а "ортодоксальная” — что форма непосредственно поддерживается самим языком. [...]

По «Orthodox Canonical Form» [нашлось](http://www.edm2.com/0510/introcpp3.html) более [человеческое объяснение](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~budd/Books/cforj/info/slides/Chapter5/tsld034.htm):

> #### The Orthodox Canonical Class Form
>
> - A default constructor: used internally to initialize objects and data members when no other value is available.
> - A copy constructor: used in the implementation of call-by-value parameters.
> - An assignment operator: used to assign one value to another.
> - A destructor: Invoked when an object is deleted.

В общем, они хотят конструктор обычный, конструктор для создания копии, оператор присвоения и деструктор. Как-то так.

Comment: Плюсанул за "православную" каноническую форму.

Answer (score 2):

Да, функция вывода на экран должна быть виртуальной. В производных классах ее переопределяете согласно условию задачи. Функция, не имеющая сведений о типе объекта, очевидно внешняя по отношению к классам и принимает указатель на базовый класс и просто вызывает функцию-член, отвечающую за вывод параметров конкретного класса. Полиморфизм в действии. Т.к. эта ф-ция-член виртуальная, то при передаче в качестве аргумента указателя на базовый или производные классы, то будут вызываться соответствующие ф-ции соответствующих классов. Если же ф-ция была бы невиртуальной, то вызывалась бы функция-член базового класса - к бабке не ходи.

Касательно ортодоксальной канонической записи - помочь не могу. С трудом представляю, что имели в виду. Могу предложить функции-члены классов делать не встроенными, а разносить declaration и definition.